# SAS: how to load a text file with a lot of spaces in between columns

Tags: sas, dataset, multiple-columns, loaddata

I have a text file downloaded from the [BLS website](https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.2.AllStatesU) that has a lot of spaces in between columns.

**Code:**

```
data unemployment;
infile 'P:\Projects\la.data.2.AllStatesU.txt' dsd firstobs=2;
input   @1  series_id : $20.
        @32 year
        @36 period : $3.
        @51 value   
        @57 footnote_codes : $1.;


run;
```

But I get a mess of errors

```
NOTE: Invalid data for year in line 2 32-53.
NOTE: Invalid data for value in line 2 51-53.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9--

3   CHAR  LAUST010000000000003          .1976.M02.         7.7. 53
    ZONE  44555333333333333333222222222203333043302222222223230
    NUMR  C15340100000000000030000000000919769D0290000000007E79
```

The period column has the first two characters right, but the year and everything else is wrong. How do I fix this?

**Snapshot of text file:**

[image: text file]

**code output:**

[image: code output]

Comment: Your file is tab-delimited (see the hexdump in the log, it shows '09' characters represented by periods between fields). Try adding `dlm='09'x` to your infile statement

Comment: That was absolutely incredible! Where is the hexdump? I don't see it in the log.

Comment: The bits that say "ZONE" "NUMR" are the hexadecimal representation of the character above them - Zone the 1st digit and Num(be)r the second digit.  `L` is `4C`, `A` is `41`, ` ` is `20`, etc.

Comment: @mjsqu Please put answers in the `answer` box below instead of in comments :)

Comment: @mjsqu : Joe is right. People having the same problem as bandcar will not open this post if it looks as if there is no answer.

Comment: Sorry everyone, was busy at work when I typed out the quick comment - upvoted the answer posted by Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file from that website

```
filename bls url 
  "https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/la/la.data.2.AllStatesU"
;
```

has tab characters in it.  That is shown in the example you posted of line 3 from the SAS LOG.

You can either tell the INFILE statement to expand the tabs into spaces and read it as fixed column format.

```
data unemployment;
  infile bls expandtabs firstobs=2 truncover;
  input
    series_id $ 1-20
    year 33-36
    period $ 41-43
    value ?? 50-60
    footnote_codes $ 65
  ;
run;
```

Or tell it that the tab character is the delimiter.

```
data unemployment;
  infile bls dlm='09'x dsd firstobs=2 truncover;
  input
    series_id :$20.
    year 
    period :$3.
    value ?? 
    footnote_codes :$1.
  ;
run;
```

Note: The `??` modifier for VALUE is because the file has a hyphen to represent missing values in that field.  The `??` input modifier will tell the data step to not flag those as data errors.